# How to compile GWT project to jar file and add it to another GWT project?

Tags: gwt

I have Three GWT projects. 2 common GWT(Bootstrap & Data Transfer Objects) projects, it doesnt contain any UI part. So, I want to compile these two projects and create jar and want to include it in third GWT project. I have done in Eclipse[Project->Export->Jar file]. It works fine. I want do it command line or through ant build.xml. Please if you know anyone, can you help on this.

Answer (score 0):

We have a similar case and here is the target we use for building an external jar for our task engine. This will build you a jar from command line that can be included in other projects. In our case we have a large project that contains all of our domain objects and some services. We wanted to include this into our task engine.

```
  <target name="taskengine-jar" depends="enhance">
    <mkdir dir="build" />
    <mkdir dir="build/META-INF"/>

    <copy todir="build/META-INF">
      <fileset dir="src/META-INF">
        <include name="persistence.xml" />
        <include name="server.properties" />
        <include name="crypto.properties" />
        <include name="sqlDrivers.xml" />
      </fileset>
    </copy>
    <jar destfile="taskengine-jobs.jar">
      <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/classes">
        <include name="com/hp/vf/server/**" />
        <include name="com/hp/vf/shared/**" />
      </fileset>
      <fileset dir="build">
        <include name="META-INF/**" />
      </fileset>
      <zipgroupfileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="axis2.jar" />
        <include name="javamail-1.4.4.jar" />
        <include name="commons-pool-1.6.jar" />
        <include name="openjpa-all-2.2.0.jar" />
        <include name="commons-logging-adapters-1.1.1.jar" />
        <include name="commons-logging-api-1.1.1.jar" />
        <include name="commons-vfs2-2.0.jar" />
        <include name="postgresql-9.0-801.jdbc4.jar" />
        <include name="poi-3.8-beta5-20111217.jar"/>
        <include name="poi-ooxml-schemas-3.8-beta5-20111217.jar"/>
        <include name="poi-ooxml-3.8-beta5-20111217.jar"/>
        <include name="itext-2.1.7.jar"/>
        <include name="REngine.jar" />
        <include name="Rserve.jar" />
        <include name="jsoup-1.6.1.jar" />
        <include name="jfreechart-1.0.13.jar" />
        <include name="jcommon-1.0.16.jar" />
      </zipgroupfileset>
      <fileset dir="war/WEB-INF/lib">
        <include name="addressing-1.1.1.mar" />
        <include name="rampart-1.1.mar" />
      </fileset>

    </jar>
    <delete dir="build" />
  </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, the most easy and flexible way is to use Maven. Each project represents the separate Maven artefact which is stored in your local repository. And only one thing you should do in your main project is to add couple of dependencies to your **POM** file. That's it. I use this schema for a long time.